# How can I apply the FillingStyle across the whole graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I want to have purple dashed line for my stem plot, as is shown here
[image: Figure 0]
but when I tried to set the options in `ListPlot` accordingly

```
ListPlot[Range[8], Filling -> 4, FillingStyle -> {Purple, Dashed}]
```

What I get is this
[image: Figure 1]

```
ListPlot[Range[8], Filling -> 4, FillingStyle -> {{Purple, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Range[8], Filling -> 4, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Purple, Dashed]]
```

[image]

[`FillingStyle >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingStyle.html)

- FillingStyle->{ $g_-$,  $g_+$} specifies that the filling should be
  done with $g_-$ when a point, curve or surface lies below the object
  being filled to, and with $g_+$ when it lies above.
- Directives can be combined using Directive[$g_1$, $g_2$,…].